# Retrieving image blob from database but it does not display a image

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, blob

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<%
 final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mani";
 final String dbUser = "root";
 final String dbPass = "";

 Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
 String message = null;  // message will be sent back to client
 Blob image = null;

 try {
     // connects to the database

 DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);
 String sql="select * from tst";
 Statement st=conn.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
 while(rs.next())

 {
     image=rs.getBlob("photo");

 %>
     <%=rs.getString("first_name") %>
     image:

    <img src="<%=image %>" width="50" height="50"/>


   <%
   }
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
System.out.println(e);
 }

  %>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>    
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This coding does not shows any error but the
image is not retrieved from the database.

But it displays a first_name column from database; it's only the
image that is not displayed in a browser.

Here this coding is written in JSP page, and I am using MySQL connector driver to connect a Java coding with JSP.

Comment: getBlob return a binary large object, this is an object not a string point to your image file. the `src=''` must point to path to an image file. Please refer to [this post](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/displaying-images-from-the-database-using-java-and-mysql/3454) to know how to display an image from database